# How to add custom class to label in Yii2 form field?

Tags: yii2, form-fields

I want to add a custom class to label tag in this code in Yii2, but I don't know how.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name',[
                    'template' => "{label}\n<div class='col-md-6'>{input}</div>\n{hint}\n{error}"])->textInput(['maxlength' => true])?>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name', [
                    'template' => "{label}\n<div class='col-md-6'>{input}</div>\n{hint}\n{error}",
                    'labelOptions' => [ 'class' => 'your_custom_class_name' ]
    ])->textInput(['maxlength' => true])?>
```

For more details refer to this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$labelOptions-detail).

**UPDATE:**

For more options use `\yii\bootstrap\ActiveField` ([link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#$labelOptions-detail)) instead of `\yii\widgets\ActiveField`

Answer (score 2):

there is a simple way and it worked for me

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['class'=>'form-control'])->label('Your Label',['class'=>'label-class']) ?>
```

Comment: Clean and simple! Thanks